# use delimiter within ngTable cells

Tags: javascript, html, css, delimiter, ngtable

I'm currently using ngTable to build a table that shows a list of email. I would like to use semi-colon as a delimiter to create a new row for every email inside the cell. What would be the best way to approach this?

```
Current: 
    Id     Email
    1      group@example.com
    2      group1@example.com;group2@example.com;group3@example.com
    3      group22@example.com

Goal is to get: 
    Id     Email
    1      group@example.com
    2      group1@example.com
           group2@example.com
           group3@example.com
    3      group22@example.com
```

http://jsfiddle.net/781qkzq0/38/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could style the td with `white-space:pre`, split the email by `;` and join with `&#10;` (line feed);

```
<td data-title="'Email'" style="white-space:pre">{{row.group_email.split(";").join("&#10;")}}</td>
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/781qkzq0/39/)